# How to receive input from GUI, apply function, then display?

Tags: python, user-interface

I wrote a function that receives input as a string, modifies it, and outputs a string.  I want to make it so that my non-computer savvy friends can use it, by adding a graphical user interface.  I want something very simple: A box where they type in the text, a button that along with hitting "Enter," submits the text, and then a place where it displays the result after my function had modified it.  I just want a way to receive input and to write output to a GUI in a way that a regular person can understand.  I have no experience with GUIs.

#### Update

In the end I used XCode to create the GUI and [PyObjC](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/) to pass the data from GUI to Python in a sort of "frontend-backend" setup.

Comment: wxpython is really simple and my preferred choice. Since you're probably not used to it, wxGlade exists (a GUI for making GUIs)

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested to get a look at http://zetcode.com/

there is a bunch of tutorial about wxPython, PyGTK and PyQt

It should guide you.

Jordi

Answer (score 0):

Does your program have to be python? (as tagged) Your description sounds like a very straightforward task.  In that case, have you considered JavaScript + HTML? Your users wouldn't need to download and install anything new, and most people have a good grasp of how to create/use web page forms.

If you're committed to a python implementation: There are a variety of different GUI toolkits (ways of creating the graphical user interface), but which one you choose will depend on how you want your program to look, what operating system you run on, ease of programming, and a variety of factors.

The widgets you describe are fairly simple (text box and button), and you might be able to accomplish your goals using Tk / Tkinter, python's ["de facto standard GUI"](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter). The advantage of this GUI toolkit is that it's bundled with python on most operating systems, hence (so long as your friends have python installed) they're ready to go. If you don't have experience building complicated installers, then you'll find that users wander off when you require them to install a dozen modules on their own. The TK script would also run on any OS.

Convenience aside, the disadvantage of Tkinter is that Tk is a fairly old and limited framework in the form commonly found with python, and it can be painful to work with for more complicated programs. (some of the online tutorials have typos like mixed case or missing quotation marks) For your task, though, the basic layout and code are pretty simple: see the TkDocs site for a demo that you can adapt.
http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are familier with C# , than you can use IronPython,
just import the Form libraries, make simple form, by putting Lable, Textbox and Button, and refer to that textbox value on Button click. you can get the WOW Gui for Python, with IronPython

Ref : [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/)